# Bug: double textarea in flag window

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

With the introduction of the new style a styling bug has presented itself in the flag dialog.

When you want to input a reason for closing other than the normal radios a textarea is shown for your input. However there are two textboxes shown at this moment. The first is partially overlapping the second one.

The image below makes the bug very clear:

[image: Screen with display bug]

Happened and tested on IE11.

Also there's a display bug on the meta asking page adding tags:

[image: Tags display bug]

Comment: This is the same issue as another bug (scoping) - fix will be rolling out shortly.

Comment: @NickCraver The 'fix' has not fixed the bug for me, on the latest Chrome on Windows 7 Professional x64.

Comment: @NickCraver See [Custom flag textarea overflows at right](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/comments/160122) could be a regression?